# Testing if a user input string contains a regular expression

Tags: c, regex, pcre

In my program I allow an administrator to define what a particular string format should be in part of a template document. This may contain a regular expression, or it might just be a literal string.

If it's a literal string, then I want to copy the string as-is automatically for all instances in the document, but if it is a (PERL) regular expression, I want to prompt the user for the correct string. This part is executed by a lower level user (non-admin) who probably doesn't understand regexes, so I don't want to present one to them as a default to be filled in.

Currently I am searching for regex characters via a simple call in a loop through the string ala:

```
if ( strchr ( "\\^.$({[+-?*|", cInputP [ iLoop ] ) != NULL ) {
    bRet = TRUE;
    break; }
```

However this seems inelegant and prone to syntax mistakes. Is there an existing function in the PCRE that would do this? The pcre_study() functions don't seem to do this, and neither can I see how to get this info from pcre_compile().

Ideally I'd also like to be able to break the string up into components of literal sub-strings and user-entered sub-strings, so that the replacement string can be prefilled with the known required characters even if it does contain regexes. Is this possible with the PCRE library as-is, or do I need to extend it with my own code?

Comment: What about [pcretest](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/pcretest/) ?

Comment: Think you might be on the right track there HamZA, the debug output seems to show some of the information I need. I guess I'll need to wade through the source to see how the magic happens...

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement is a bit confusing, since it implies a somewhat false division; in fact all strings are regular expressions, matching themselves (possibly excepting strings that contain invalid regular expressions, of course).

So it's a bit weird to try to detect if a string is a "literal string or a regular expression".

It might be better to let the user tell the program explicitly if a literal string is enough, or if using a regular expression is desired.

Comment: The "false division" is necessary because I need to know whether I can automatically do the replacement as-is or not. For example, if the user entered string is "150kV", then I can automatically replace it; however if it is "[[:digit:]]+kV" then I cannot and require extra user input for the replacement string.